# Jquery loop over radio buttons & find lowest price on container div

Tags: jquery

Could you use Jquery to find the lowest price and then add a class to the surrounding  and the change the 'checked="checked"' to the proper option?

```
<div><input type="radio" name="RateID" value="1" checked="checked"/>UPS Ground - $10.91</div>
<div><input type="radio" name="RateID" value="2" />UPS 3 Day Select - $14.34</div>
<div><input type="radio" name="RateID" value="3" />UPS 2nd Day Air - $19.22</div>
<div><input type="radio" name="RateID" value="4" />UPS Next Day Air Saver - $36.19</div>
<div><input type="radio" name="RateID" value="5" />USPS Priority Mail - $6.35</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you could, something like this

```
$('[name="RateID"]').sort(function(a,b) {
    return $(a).closest('div').text().split('-').pop().replace(/[^\d.]/g, '' ) -
           $(b).closest('div').text().split('-').pop().replace(/[^\d.]/g, '' );
}).first()
  .prop('checked', true)
  .closest('div')
  .addClass('someClass');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/s47dcunh/3/)

Comment: `$10.91` is not lowest price i guess!

Comment: @DhavalMarthak - like that!

Comment: @adeneo Now that looks great.. ;) rewarded too :)

Comment: @adeneo - thanks for answer.. now if you change the html to make other div smaller price, your code doesn't select the lowest price

Comment: Give me a second to look at it. This would be freakishly much easier if you could add a data attribute or something that holds the price, instead of trying to extract it

Comment: It's just the darn regex to try and extract the price, I gave up and just split and popped it.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code.It would work for you.

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
        var minPrice = jQuery('input[type="radio"]:checked').closest('div').text().split('-').pop().replace(/[^\d.]/g, '' );
        var value;
        jQuery('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
          var a = $(this).closest('div').text().split('-').pop().replace(/[^\d.]/g, '' );

          if(minPrice > parseFloat(a))
          {
            minPrice = a;
            value =  $(this).val();
          }
        })

        jQuery('input[value="'+value+'"]').attr('checked','true');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code in

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
values=Array();
jQuery('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
test=jQuery(this).val();
values.push(test);
})

max = Math.max.apply(Math,values);
jQuery('input[value="'+max+'"]').attr('checked','true');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.. but it always select last checkbox regardless of smaller price i assign to other div